# Insert unicode symbols to edittext

Tags: android, unicode, android-edittext

How to insert Unicode symbols to edit text?
In iOS we can do it by just by specifying the code i.e `\U0001F68A` .What about android ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
editText.setText("\u00A9 2013 by John Smith");
```

will put the copyright symbol followed by " 2013 by John Smith" into the the EditText editText.

Answer (score 4):

```
editText.getText().append("\uD83D\uDE0A");
```

Comment: I didn't get it to work until I tried "\u00A9" for the copyright symbol.

Comment: @Fedor i've got emoji from this code \uD83D\uDE0A but when i am pressing backspace key, it takes two presses (Because of two Unicodes) for deletion. any solution?